# Printing the i and i+1 element of a list using ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor

I want to print the contents of a list by printing, at the same time, the i and i+1 element. This is a dummy example of how you can do it in Java or any backend programming language:

```
List list = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i<list.size() - 1; i++)
   System.out.println(list[i] + " " + list[i+1]);
```

What I want is to achieve the same behaviour in Angular using the ngFor directive. I tried using the index, but for some reason I can't get the ngFor to iterate until the length - 1 element.

Edit: To be more specific about the problem:

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let item of items; let index=index">
   <div class="col">
     {{items[index]}}
   </div>
   <div class="col">
     {{items[index+1]}}
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the expected outcome? can you please add that in your post too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `odd` local variable:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index; let odd = odd">
   <li *ngIf="odd">{{items[i]}} - {{items[i+1]}}</li>
</ng-container>
```

But using `even` is safer (because it won't break the application if the length of the array is even):

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index; let even = even">
   <li *ngIf="even">{{items[i-1]}} - {{items[i]}}</li>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: This is the behavior I'm looking for but for some reason I can't put it properly on the structure I posted above, that with two columns. I want the i element on the first column, and the i+1 element on the second column (that will compose the first row) and so on. It doesn't give any errors, but for some reason it prints the items at different positions one from another, ignoric the row and column structure.

Answer (score 3):

Well if you go to the documentation or any other blog regarding `*ngFor`, you might encounter `index` after a semicolon like this:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items; index as i;">{{item}} - {{ items[i+1] }}</li>
```

[More to find here.](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vtszd1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: But this still doesn't let me print the {{item[i]}} and {{item[i+1]}} at the same time. I want to print the actual i and i+1 elements (on different columns, like in the example I provided above), not their indexes.